# There is no output for the same:

Tags: java, class, inheritance, methods

When I compile and try to run this in eclipse there is no output. I have been trying every way possible.

```
class let {

    String name;
    int age;
    int rollno;
}

public class class_method  {

   public static void main(){

       let person1 = new let();
       person1.name = "Ritwik";
       person1.age = 14;
       person1.rollno = 20;

       System.out.println( " Hello my name is :" + person1.name);

       Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
   }
}
```

Comment: Its working correctly.what problem you faced?

Comment: Please follow the conventions about the name of a class: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html . Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are facing this behavior because of the signature of your main method
In java it is compulsory for the main method to have following signature

```
public static void main(String args[]) { //Lots of code here }
```

For more details, [look here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html)

**Update**

This is why **String[] args** is important in main function definition. Following is an excerpt from oracle docs that I have posted a link to

> The main method accepts a single argument: an array of elements of type String.
>
> This array is the mechanism through which the runtime system passes information to your application.

Comment: Thank you so much but why exactly is the String args[] necessary?

Comment: You can go through the link, it is the official documentation by oracle. You can also check my updated answer for a little hint

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting the String[] args in main method argument.

Try this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class let {

    String name;
    int age;
    int rollno;
}

public class ClassMthod  {

   public static void main(String[] args){

       let person1 = new let();
       person1.name = "Ritwik";
       person1.age = 14;
       person1.rollno = 20;

       System.out.println( " Hello my name is :" + person1.name);

       Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much but why exactly is the String args[] necessary?

Comment: Its purpose is to pass command line arguments to main method. Developers of java designed it this way. To understand more about main method signature follow https://www.journaldev.com/12552/public-static-void-main-string-args-java-main-method